# Should I list non technical achievements and roles on my SO careers profile

Tags: careers

Should I list previous work employment, skills or certificates not directly related to my career path (software development) on SE careers? I am relatively new in my career with lack of relevant work experience.

I initially enquired over at SE meta because I wanted to know what the 'algorithm' was in how our profiles were being chosen and listed to interested employers. However no-one could give me an answer, and the question was closed while I was pointed here.

I personally think these non technical skills are valuable experience so I list them on normal CVs and LinkedIn. However, SE gives the vibe of quite a 'technical' site, which I feel would attract 'technical' employers looking for candidates with specific language and technology experience.

As such, I feel if I was to list these 'non related' roles even among the related roles, an employer might look at my profile and think '*this person has missed the entire point of this site...*'

Comment: If the CV is a little thin due to age put them down. It might be a talking point. Remember the CV is a mechanism to get an interview. People do not hire drones

Comment: This feels very opinion based.  Some people will say yes, some people will say no.  There's no definitive answer.  As such, I am voting to close.

Comment: @JaneS some will say yes, and some will say no, I agree - but if they explain those opinions and the reasons behind them, they could help the OP come to a reasonable decision.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I list previous work employment, skills or certificates not
>   directly related to my career path (software development) on SE
>   careers? I am relatively new in my career with lack of relevant work
>   experience.

That seems like a reasonable thing to do if you are very light on specific, relevant work experience.

But make sure you aren't writing "what I did in junior high school"-type jobs or skills.